# Place model image in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I am trying to display an image stored in the database (actually a varbinary) and trying to display it in a "img" tag.  Simple View:

```
 <table style="font-size:x-small">
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.CandidateId, new { @id = "txtCandidateId"})
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(x=>x.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            AD Account User Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtUsername" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img id="img" src="" alt="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then in script:

```
 var cand;
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    cand = function () { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) }();
    var source = "/InProcess/RetrieveImage/" + cand.CandidateId;
    $("#img").attr("src", source);
});
```

Then in controller:

```
 public ActionResult RetrieveImage(string candidate)
    {
        byte[] pdf;
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Repository.GetCandidatePdf(candidate).CopyTo(memStream);
            pdf = memStream.ToArray();
        }
        if (pdf != null)
        {
            return File(pdf, "cover/jpg");
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

I can see the correct id, which is a uniqueidentifer, in the JS of the page and the action is getting called but the candidateId is null.  Anybody have any ideas why?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Default routing needs that you call your parameter "Id" and not "candidate", replace it with id and retry.

Comment: Why are you returning a PDF? You cannot put a PDF file into an `<img />` element.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the route parameters in ASP.NET MVC are `{controller}`, `{action}`, and `{id}` - `controller` and `action` are handled for you, and `id` needs to be the name of the action paramemter:

```
public ActionResult RetrieveImage(String id) {
    ...
}
```

Also your Content-Type is incorrect, it should be `image/jpeg` if you're returning a JPEG image, or `application/pdf` if you're returning an Adobe PDF document. However you cannot load a PDF into an `<img />` element.

Comment: Thanks, I do see the correct ID coming through now but the image is empty on the page.  I change to the line "return File(pdf, "image/jpeg"); but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Dean.DePue that's because you're not returning a JPEG. Your code shows you're returning a PDF file. PDFs are not images.

Comment: actually it is a memory stream that is converted into a byte array with memStream.ToArray().  How could I do it otherwise?

Comment: @Dean.DePue You're still returning a PDF file. The PDF file is in the memory stream. It is not an "image" for because it isn't a JPEG, GIF, PNG, Bitmap, TIFF, etc. PDFs are fundamentally different.

Comment: How can I change the PDF stream into an image?